# постоянные проблемы с npm i что ему нужно?npm audit fix --force не помогает а просто по кругу все

Tags: npm

```
    npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
    npm WARN audit Updating resolve-url-loader to 4.0.0,which is a SemVer major change.
    
    added 5 packages, removed 17 packages, changed 2 packages, and audited 794 packages in 4s
    
    85 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    
    # npm audit report
    
    node-forge  <1.0.0
    Prototype Pollution in node-forge debug API. - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5rrq-pxf6-6jx5
    fix available via `npm audit fix`
    node_modules/node-forge
      selfsigned  1.1.1 - 1.10.14
      Depends on vulnerable versions of node-forge
      node_modules/selfsigned
        webpack-dev-server  2.5.0 - 4.7.2
        Depends on vulnerable versions of selfsigned
        node_modules/webpack-dev-server
          laravel-mix  1.2.0 - 6.0.0-beta.17 || >=6.0.19
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/laravel-mix
    
    postcss  <8.2.13
    Severity: moderate
    Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5
    fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
    Will install resolve-url-loader@2.3.2, which is a breaking change
    node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
      resolve-url-loader  0.0.1-experiment-postcss || 3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
      node_modules/resolve-url-loader
    
    6 vulnerabilities (4 low, 2 moderate)
    
    To address issues that do not require attention, run:
      npm audit fix
    
    To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
      npm audit fix --force



вот package.json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "site.dev": "npm run site.development",
        "site.development": "cross-env process.env.section=site NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "site.watch": "npm run site.development -- --watch",
        "site.prod": "npm run site.production",
        "site.production": "cross-env process.env.section=site NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "admin.dev": "npm run admin.development",
        "admin.development": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "admin.watch": "npm run admin.development -- --watch",
        "admin.prod": "npm run admin.production",
        "admin.production": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "manager.dev": "npm run manager.development",
        "manager.development": "cross-env process.env.section=manager NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "manager.watch": "npm run manager.development -- --watch",
        "manager.prod": "npm run manager.production",
        "manager.production": "cross-env process.env.section=manager NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.13",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
        "vue-search-select": "^2.9.5",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

Comment: Ничего не делать